# Large file sharing with JIRA

Tags: jira, confluence, atlassian-crowd

We are immigrating from local network to Atlassian Jira. We are designers team so sometime we need to share a very big size file (>200MB). Is there any way to setup a service like Tortoise SVN on Jira or a file sharing center from local connect to JIra. Although Jira allows us to attach a file, but each time we need to download it, do something on this file, and then re-upload to send.

Any idea is appreciate, thanks so much

Comment: JIRA and "local network" (whatever that's supposed to mean) are most likely not something where you'd say "migrate". JIRA is an issue tracker, not a file hosting platform.

Comment: I mean we are using Jira for issue tracking but we also want to put the hosting file share into Atlassian so we don't need to have local file server (it likes Adobe Creative Cloud Team - for designers)

Comment: Atlassian doesn’t offer a file exchange tool. Local file servers are the way to go for big files.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I agree with you that local file servers should be more reasonable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jira supports [Bitbucket](https://www.atlassian.com/software/bitbucket). It's a type of version control similar to Tortoise SVN (it's better in my opinion).

I've personally used the Bitbucket feature back when it was known as Stash. It works very well for source control for code, and I'm sure it will serve your purpose well being used as a file share (we even considered using it this way at my former job). It should in fact track changes in files as well when properly setup - code or not.

There are also many other add-ons for Jira that look like they will serve you well including...

[Comala Share It](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.keinoby.confluence.plugins.share-attachments/server/overview)

[File Sharing for Confluence](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/no.kantega.fileshare.fileshare-plugin.confluence/server/overview)

Comment: Git (which is what you Stash/Bitbucket wraps around) is not suitable for big files. But IIRC Bitbucket supports Git-LFS now.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply Timmy, but I checked some documents and they said Bitbucket needs to link to Git or Xcode which support for coding only(Thanks Danniel B). For the files share, is it possible or we need another plug-in

Comment: It's likely you'll need another plugin, possibly one of the ones I've listed at the end of my answer, but as I said they _look_ like they will serve you well.  I'm not totally sure if it's what you're looking for having never used either of those. Typically we use to share large files on network drives and just download them locally when needed.

Comment: Oh, i see. Thanks for your suggestion plug-in. But it look likes we need to wait for newer service which can support files sharing. But your rest of plug-in also really cool to check.